# Updating older Keras models with deprecation warnings

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an older Keras model file that works perfectly. When I try to load it in `tensorflow==1.13.1` however, I'm given a host of warnings:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("best.h5")
```

> WARNING:tensorflow:From .pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:435: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Colocations handled automatically by placer.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From .pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Use tf.cast instead.

Assuming I don't want to retrain the model, how can I update it to not give these errors? If needed, the original network (a simple 1D covnet) is below:

```
M = keras.Sequential()
M.add(Embedding(n_vocab, n_window, input_length=n_window))

M.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation="relu"))
M.add(MaxPooling1D(5))

M.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation="relu"))
M.add(MaxPooling1D(5))

M.add(Flatten())
M.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
M.add(Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax"))
```

Answer (score 0):

These aren't errors, they relate to the internal Keras implementation in tensorflow, there is not much you can do other than to wait for `tf.keras` to update their implementation and not use deprecated functions.